# JavaScript: A very simple way to implement electronic signature

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a very simple way in JS to make an electronic signature that can be handled with as much ease as checksums (or hash)?

So if this is the scenario:

```
------------------------------------
      Locked section for client
------------------------------------
| YYYY.MM.DD  ......................|
| ........... ......................|
| Bla bla bla ......................|
| Bla bla bla Bla bla bla..Bla bla .|
| Bla bla bla Bla bla bla..Bla bla .|
| Bla bla bla Bla bla bla..Bla bla .|
| Bla bla bla Bla bla bla..Bla bla .|
| Bla bla bla ......................|
| Bla bla bla ......................|
------------------------------------
|    HASH: HA2S2EM3CA12EDIAJED      |
------------------------------------
"Open" comment textfield for clients
------------------------------------
| HE34ADOV2DSASA452123 ...(signer A)|
| GHEAVOED12dHSAV2123J ...(signer B)|
```

`HE34ADOV2DSASA452123` is generated by a private key owned by the signer.

Then the decryption (with some sort of public key) of `HE34ADOV2DSASA452123` would give something like `YYYY.MM.DD Bla bla bla` or return the hash (`HA2S2EM3CA12EDIAJED`) of the section.

Likewise the decryption of `GHEAVOED12dHSAV2123J` would give something like `YYYY.MM.DD Bla bla bla` or return the hash (`HA2S2EM3CA12EDIAJED`) of the section.

---

Note there is no requirement for this to be secured against evil master minds, just against "layman" fraud...

Comment: Could you explain use case a little? You have message + some encrypted text (which can be decrypted to "YYYY.MM.DD Bla bla bla"). Someone knows how it was encrypted. What you mean by "Everyone can read"?

Comment: @Meredian I updated the example to be more explanatory.

Comment: If the server stores the salt, everybody who can change the data can generate a new hash, so you need some way of keypinning. E.g. publishing the hash somewhere, so that every change gets documented

Comment: Unless you need it be human verifiable, RSA signatures should suffice. [TweetNaCl JS](https://tweetnacl.js.org) is very well-known

Comment: I need it to be human verifiable..

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Why not just use a common hash and public- private key procedure, and cryptojs or the sjcl? And what exactly are you missing, a hash or a signature algorithm?

Comment: @Lux Im trying to find a solution to my question without reinventing something that already exist. I have limited knowledge about encryption and find the libs, I come across, very difficult to use.

Answer (score 5):

Electronic signatures are by definition much more complex then a hash. While you can just generate a hash from a message, for a digital signature you usually want a private key and enforce that only someone who knows the private key can produce a valid signature. Next you obviously need the corresponding public key to verify the message.

So usually you have 3 steps for this:

1. you need to create a public/private key pair.
2. you need to sign your message with the private key on a system that is trustful. Only this system should have the private key.
3. you verify the message with the public key, to ensure that the trustful system has signed it.

So the first interesting question is, how do you want to store/distribute your keys, and on what kind of systems do you want to sign/verify? It's a common use case that you sign and verify in different programming languages. However for now lets assume you want to do everything in JavaScript.

Also always remember a simple problem:
If you can't be sure the message is from the valid sender, how can you ensure that the public key you are using to verify the message is from the valid sender? You could distribute it with your software, but for a website you have to trust your TLS connection for this, and if you trust your TLS connection you can also use it to transfer the message itself.

I think the best solution is to use the [Web Cryptography API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/). [Here](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples) you can find helpful examples.

---

First you need to generate your keys:

```
async function generateKey() {
  const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
      name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
      modulusLength: 4096,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: {
        name: "SHA-512"
      },
    },
    true,
    ["sign", "verify"]
  );

  return {
    privateKey: await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
      "jwk",
      key.privateKey,
    ),
    publicKey: await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
      "jwk",
      key.publicKey,
    ),
  };
}
```

`window.crypto.subtle.exportKey` gives you a JSON that you can transform back and forth to a simple string by `JSON.strinify`/`JSON.parse` so you can store it somewhere.

---

The next step is to sign your message. Notice that you probably want to do this at a different time then generating the keys.

```
async function sign(privateKeyJwk, message) {
  const privateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", privateKeyJwk, {
    name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        hash: {name: "SHA-512"},
  }, false, ['sign']);
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(message);

  const signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign({
      name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    },
    privateKey,
    data,
  );

  // converts the signature to a colon seperated string
  return new Uint8Array(signature).join(':');
}
```

this function takes the jwk of the private key we created in the first step and a simple string as a message to sign. It returns a signature as colon separated string. This works for now, even if Base64 for example would be more efficient.

---

Now the last step is to verify your message. You probably want to do this later on a different machine, where you only have the public key and a maybe corrupted message and you want to verify if the message was corrupted or not. Its absolutely essential that you can trust that the private key was not corrupted.

```
async function verify(publicKeyJwk, signatureStr, message) {
    const signatureArr = signatureStr.split(':').map(x => +x);
  const signature = new Uint8Array(signatureArr).buffer

  const publicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", publicKeyJwk, {
    name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        hash: {name: "SHA-512"},
  }, false, ['verify']);
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(message);

  const ok = await window.crypto.subtle.verify({
      name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    },
    publicKey,
    signature,
    data
  );
  return ok;
}
```

for this you need the jwk of the public key that we created in the first step, the message used in the second step as a string and the signature created by the second step as the colon separated string.

This will result in a boolean indicating if the message is valid or not.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to try and answer my question. Really appreciate it. I must admit that I was hoping that there would be a more simple way - like hashing. Most physical signatures today are authenticated by recognizing the handwriting - not the most secure way but similar to hashing. There aren't any private and public hashing technic/packages out there?

Comment: Hashing is, by definition, not a public/private key procedure. Hashing is an algorithm that transforms a value to a shorter value. For example the modulo is a valid hashing algorithm. And `3%3=0` and `6%3=0`. If you have a public/private key, you have the complexity of creating it and managing it. What exactly were you hoping could be more simple, and what exactly is your use case? Maybe we have an X/Y problem here, so please talk a bit more about your concrete use case for this.

Answer (score 3):

Try node module [XML Advanced Electronic Signatures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xadesjs).

It uses Web Crypto for cryptographic operations. Hence it can be used both in browsers and Node.js.

Comment: Depending on your usecase, you may also want to consider straight forward PGP, e.g. in node: https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for something more simple.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a proper "[digital signature](https://signyourdoc.com/)" in the technical sense - e.g. using a private key to sign and a public key to verify the signature. The "qualified" signatures need to be issued by a qualified provider that is basically a trusted Certificate Authority. The keys for placing qualified signatures have to be issued on secure devices (smart cards and HSMs) so that nobody but the owner can have access to the private key.

But the legal distinction between advanced and qualified signatures isn't entirely clear - the Regulation explicitly states that non-qualified signatures also have legal value. Working with qualified signatures (with smartcards) in browsers is a horrifying user experience - in most cases, it goes through a Java Applet, which works basically just on Internet Explorer and a special build of Firefox nowadays. Alternatives include desktop software and local service JWS applications that handle the signing, but smartcards are a big issue and offtopic at the moment.

So, how do we allow users to "place" an electronic signature? I had an idea that this could be done entirely using the WebCrypto API that's more or less supported in browsers these days. The idea is as follows:

Let the user type in a password for the purpose of signing.
Derive a key from the password (e.g. using PBKDF2).
Sign the contents of the form that the user is submitting with the derived key.
Store the signature alongside the rest of the form data.
Optionally, store the derived key for verification purposes.
Here's a JavaScript gist with an implementation of that flow.

Many of the pieces are taken from the very helpful webcrypto examples repo. The hex2buf, buf2hex, and str2ab functions are utilities (that sadly are not standard in JS).

What the code does is straightforward, even though it's a bit verbose. All the operations are chained using promises and "then," which, to be honest, is a bit tedious to write and read (but inevitable I guess): [Class 2 Digital Signature](https://signyourdoc.com/class-2-digital-signature/) , [Class 3 Digital Signature](https://signyourdoc.com/class-3-digital-signature/)

The password is loaded as a raw key (after transforming to an array buffer).
A secret key is derived using PBKDF2 (with 100 iterations).
The secret key is used to do an HMAC "signature" on the content filled in by the user.
The signature and the key are stored (in the UI in this example).
Then the signature can be verified using: the data, the signature, and the key.

Comment: We build a product that uses WebCrypto API and PKIjs to do PAdES signatures (and verification) in the browser. You can see verification with this link. https://manage.hancock.ink/document?url=https://peculiarventures.github.io/ExamplePDFs/signed/signed_example_diploma.pdf. We also added support for smart cards by creating this middleware that acts as a bridge between OS and web https://fortifyapp.com